# Opening a Batch file from another (Including Java)

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am writing a batch file that runs other batch files (and some other things) for easier methods of running my Minecraft Bungeecord server.

This is the batch file, Run.bat, I am running from the server managing batch file:

```
@echo off
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar BungeeCord.jar
pause
```

And this is the section in the server managing batch where I run the file:

```
:start
SET PATH=C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files
cd %PATH%\Bungeecord
start Run.bat
```

When I run the Run.bat from the server managing batch this is what the cmd shows:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I run the Run.bat just by double clicking it, it works just fine.

Anyone have the same issue, or know how to fix it?

Comment: the issue isn't running the .bat file, it's the fact that the java command doesn't work when I do so

Comment: Is the full path of `java.exe` present in the %PATH% environment variable? See it in control panel.

Comment: The java only doesn't work when the batch file that it is in is ran from another batch file. When I just run the batch file that the java command is in without the using of another, it works just fine.

Comment: May be there is problem in `set` command. Use this tip. For example I want to add `C:\foo\bar` in PATH. Use `set` command as: `SET PATH=C:\foo\bar;%PATH%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `SET PATH=C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files
>   cd %PATH%\Bungeecord`

may be breaking your code. 
Could you please delete that, and instead just type this?

> `CD "C:\Users\micah_000\Desktop\Server Files\Bungeecord"`

Comment: It was like that before, with the same results

Comment: Can you find where `javaw.exe` is located? Normally, on an x64 system, it is located here: `C:\Program Files\Java\your java version\bin\javaw.exe`.

Comment: I just switched it and you were right! The PATH was breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
start run.bat
```

with either:

```
%comspec% /k run.bat
```

or

```
%comspec% /c run.bat
```